# Test printing functions in C - unit tests, check

Tags: c, unit-testing, printing, void

I'm trying to write unit test for C code using [check](https://libcheck.github.io/check/doc/check_html/check_toc.html#SEC_Contents). However, I have stumbled over tests for void methods without return statements, which only use printf(). How can I test the output from these methods? Is there any way to redirect the output to, i.e., an array of chars I can compare? I have found some answers for Python, but none for C.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try [`freopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html)?

```
// untested, no guarantees
START_TEST(test_silentfunction) {
    // redirect stdout to file
    freopen("/tmp/OBSCURITY_fb78trerbwedftwefnwdfyutew.txt", "w", stdout);
    silentfunction();
    // return stdout to default tty output
    freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);

    // check contents of file /tmp/OBSCURITY_fb78trerbwedftwefnwdfyutew.txt
    remove("/tmp/OBSCURITY_fb78trerbwedftwefnwdfyutew.txt");
}
END_TEST
```

Comment: If one wanted to restore `stdout` to what it was before (in case it was not `"/dev/tty"`), any ideas?

Comment: Since `stdout` has file descriptor `1`, one can use this code snippet to find out what `stdout` is before using `freopen()`: `int get_stdout_filepath(char* output, size_t output_size) { ssize_t res = readlink("/proc/self/fd/1", output, output_size); return (res > 0 && res < (ssize_t) output_size) ? 1 : 0; }`. This code is not portable (requires `<unistd.h>` and `readlink()` function), and returns `1` on success and `0` on failure.